# How to post data URLSearchParams With Fetch in IE 11

Tags: javascript, post, fetch, url-encoding

When I am trying to post bodydata using URLSearchParams in `fetch`, its working in Chrome v72 and Edge v40 but not on IE11 (with polyfills).

On IE11: I am getting this error:

> Error: unsupported BodyInit type

I am using the following polyfills for Edge/IE/etc browsers:

- whatwg-fetch: "3.0.0" (A window.fetch polyfill)
- url-search-params-polyfill: "5.0.0" (a simple polyfill for javascript `URLSearchParams`)

  const bodyData = new URLSearchParams()
  Object.keys(configJson).map(key => {
    bodyData.append(encodeURIComponent(key), 
    encodeURIComponent(configJson[key]))
  })

  const opts = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: bodyData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    }
  }

  fetch(endPointUrl, opts)

Comment: Passed the body data like  this,

`const bodyData = Object.keys(configJson).map(key => {
      return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(configJson[key])
    }).join('&')

    const opts = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: bodyData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
      }
    }`

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below

Example your request body

```
{..., body : objToBodyObj(obj) ..}
```

Below is function

```
function objToBodyObj(obj) {
  var str = "";
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (str != "") {
      str += "&";
    }
    str += key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]);
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: I did this like below,

`const bodyData = Object.keys(configJson).map(key => {
      return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(configJson[key])
    }).join('&')

    const opts = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: bodyData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
      }
    }`